# Meaning of "ask of"

Tags: phrases

What is the meaning of the phrase *ask of* in the following sentence?

> Trust and security are important for any application; before we move on to the
>   meat of accessing data, let’s make sure the browser itself is capable of doing everything you’re **asking of** it.

It is extracted from a technical book.

Comment: Where's the research?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This meaning of [ask](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/ask_1) (definition 7) is mentioned in the OALD:

> *expect/demand*
>   [transitive] to expect or demand something ...
>   **ask something of somebody** *You're asking too much of him*.

So, "doing everything you’re asking of it" means doing everything you expect or demand of it.

Comment: That sense is derived by the use of the preposition *of* -- see your own example.

Answer (score 3):

"**doing everything you're asking of it**" means "**doing everything you're asking it to do**".

Which, in the case of an inanimate thing, means "**doing everything you're trying to get it to do**".

Answer (score 2):

'Asking of' here is in the same sense as 'demanding of.' Asking something to someone (or in this case, something - the browser) means putting a question. Asking something of someone is like making a request or asking a favour. It implies involvement of proactive effort on the part of the other party in the process of meeting your requirement(s).

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find anything about this on dictionaries in order to explain it with definitions, but basically the meaning is this one:

> Trust and security are important for any application; before we move on to the meat of accessing data, let’s make sure the browser itself is capable of doing everything you’re ***asking it to do***.