# Difference between "ask of me" and "ask me"

Tags: grammar

Can somebody please explain the difference between "ask of me" and "ask me"? Why do we use "of" between ask and me?

Comment: **ask something of someone or something** to request or demand something from someone, something, or a group. *I want to ask something of you. We will ask that of the board of directors. You should ask that of your database.* http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/ask+of

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/37/messages/779.html http://english.stackexchange.com/q/38136/14666 NB: **Cited post has incorrect/incomplete accepted answer**

Answer (score 2):

"Ask of someone" would tend to imply asking for something from someone, perhaps a favor. Whereas, "ask someone" simply means to ask someone something, like a question.

Comment: Perhaps more clearly illustrated with "They are asking too much of him," vs *"They are asking him too much."

Answer (score -4):

I think they are both like a question, just with different usage between "ask something of someone" and "ask someone something".